# Display name when hover over plugin icon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I have made a QGIS plugin (Python) and when I hover my mouse/cursor over the icon in QGIS the name of the plugin seem to be "Plugins Toolbar". I have searched all .py scripts in the directory of the plugin and can't find any reference to "Plugins Toolbar".

How do I change the name of this "icon text"?

[image: See picture]

Answer (score 5):

In your *plugin.py* file (or whatever you named the main file), look inside the `initGui()` function. You'll want to change the `text` parameter for the icon::

```
def initGui(self):
"""Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

icon_path = ':/plugins/example/icon.png'
self.add_action(
    icon_path,
    text=self.tr(u'Plugin_button'),
    callback=self.run,
    parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
```

Comment: You are quick, I was writing the same answer :). Just I want to add that the OP should reload the plugin using the `Plugin Reloader` to see the changes.

Comment: @ahmadhanb - I had my coffee :). Thank you for your tip, the plugin should indeed be reloaded such as with the `Plugin Reloader`... plugin.

Comment: @SunTour Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: How do i "accept" the answer?  I am a bit new here..